# Flyway migration in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to add an entry to Postgresql using such a request

```
insert into customer (id, email, name, number_telephone) VALUES (public.hibernate_sequence_customer.nextval, 'abc@jar.ru' , 'Henry', '89132547898');
```

, but flyway throws an error

```
Error: table "hibernate_sequence_customer" is missing in the FROM clause
```

In the project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbfg4.png)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score 1):

The next value of your sequence is [accessed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) via `nextval('public.hibernate_sequence_customer')`, not dot notation.

```sql
insert into customer (
    id,
    email,
    name,
    number_telephone)
VALUES (
    nextval('public.hibernate_sequence_customer'),
    'abc@jar.ru' ,
    'Henry',
    '89132547898');
```

but if you define `id` column as `serial`, you don't need to call the sequence at all.

```sql
create table customer (
    id serial primary key,
    email text,
    name text,
    number_telephone text);
```

Just skip it in your `insert`:

```
insert into customer (
    email,
    name,
    number_telephone)
VALUES (
    'abc@jar.ru' ,
    'Henry',
    '89132547898');
```

If you later need to refer to the sequence responsible for the `id` column - to get its current value, for example - you can use [`currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('customer','id'))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-info.html#:%7E:text=pg_get_serial_sequence%20(%20table%20text,pg_get_serial_sequence(%27sometable%27%2C%20%27id%27))%3B).